# want to separate frontend and backend user in yii2

Tags: yii2

as there is only **user** table in yii2 advanced. so user can login to both frontend and backend with same credential . we want saperate it out.

so I created **frontuser** table ,with same structure as of user table.
then created its **model** using gii model generator

made it as common model/user.

here is frontend/model/frontuser

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "frontuser".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 */
//class Frontuser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
class Frontuser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
    public static function tableName()
    {
       return '{{%frontuser}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
       return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }



    /**
     *  inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
}
```

and in frontend/config/main.php

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        // 'user' => [
        //     'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        //     'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        //     'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        // ],
        'user' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\User', // basic class
                'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\Frontuser', // your admin model
                'enableAutoLogin' => true,
                'loginUrl' => '/admin/frontend/login',
            ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
            'defaultRoles'=> ['guest'],
            ],   
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

but still ,I sign up ,entry goes in user table ..
I want to use **user** table for backend user
and **frontuser** table for frontend user
how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create table in database same field as user table name it frontuser
2. Copy common\models\user.php and place it on frontend\models\frontuser.php
   make following changes

   • `use yii\helpers\Security;`
   • `class Frontuser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface`
   •`(return '{{%frontuser}}';)`
3. Copy common\models\LoginForm.php in frontend\models\LoginForm.php just change

   namespace frontend\models;
4. frontend\sitecontroller.php
   • `use frontend\models\LoginForm;`
5. frontend\models\signup.php just change

   • `Replace common to frontend.`
    • `new Frontuser`

Comment: Very good! The problem is that, the user login check is passing positive, but the user is still guest and will be routed back to the login page with 'Login' Tab. Additional change in the main.php have to be done. I will do the addition in a separate answer based on your recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

A way  could be based on modelMap

in Your frontend/config/main.php

you could reassign  the model map for user module  and your user model point to the table you need eg:

```
'modules' => [
    .......
    'user' => [
        'class' => your_user_class',  // eg:  'class' => 'yii2\user\Module' 
                                      // check in Yii2 / Yiisoft vendor 
                                      // or in your vendor  for the right module
        'admins' => ['your_admin'],
        'modelMap' => [
            'User'      => 'frontend\models\FrontUser',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check what form model is used in sign up action. Probably it is `frontend\models\SignupForm`. And SignupForm uses `common\models\User` as user model. You should change it to `frontend\models\Frontuser`. So check login, logout, signup, reset password actions. Change model to `frontend\models\Frontuser` everyware in frontend.

Comment: frontend signup form values goes in frontuser table but when I login it search in user table ...how to make login form to validate credential in frontuser table?

Comment: check common\models\LoginForm.php. Add
"use frontend\models\Frontuser;"
and change User to Frontuser in getUser() method

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer of Goli i would like to make one addition and one correction!

```
 1. Copy user table in database and name it frontuser
 2. Copy common\models\user.php and place it on frontend\models\frontuser.php

 make following changes:

     class Frontuser extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface

     ...(return '{{%frontuser}}';)

 3. Copy common\models\LoginForm.php in frontend\models\LoginForm.php just change namespace frontend\models;

 4. frontend\sitecontroller.php

         use frontend\models\Frontuser;
         use frontend\models\LoginForm;
         use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
         use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
         use frontend\models\SignupForm;
         use frontend\models\ContactForm;

 5. frontend\models\signup.php just change

     Replace common to frontend
     new Frontuser

 6. Change in config\main.php

    'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\Frontuser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two way : 
first one is add field type in user table to separate admin and user 
but in your way you should declare another component in web.php

```
'admin' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\admin',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'idParam'         => '_admin'
    ],
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'idParam'         => '_user'
    ],
```

and in access behaviour backend add this parametr

'user'  => Yii::$app->admin,

Answer (score 0):

you can put below code in forntend/config/main.php under components

```
'user' => [ 
                        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
                        'enableAutoLogin' => true ,
                        'identityCookie' => [
                                'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for frontend
                                'path'=>'/frontend/web'  // correct path for the frontend app.
                        ]
                ],
```

you can put below code in backend/config/main.php under components

```
 'admin' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\adminUsers',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
                'identityCookie' => [
                        'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
                        'path' => '/advanced/backend/web' // correct path for backend app.
                ]
        ],
```

you can copy common user identityClass and change that name to adminUsers and paste this file in backend models.

you can get user session data for frontend LIKE Yii::$app->user->identity->id
you can get user session data for frontend LIKE Yii::$app->admin->identity->id